# ASP.NET MVC arquitectura DDD(Domain Driven Design)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, patrones-de-diseño, ddd

DDD(***Domain Driven Design***), Es un conjunto de patrones principos y práticas que nos ayudan a resolver y entender los problemas del negocio(Dominio) en el diseño de sistemas orientados a objetos. DDD es un tema muy amplio.

Vengo usando la arquitectura N - Capas desde Windows Forms pero en ASP.NET MVC me surge una duda ya que soy principiante trabajando en sistemas web.

Enfoquemonos en la arquitectura DDD.

[image: Domain Driven Design]

> Vamos directo al problema que tengo. Partiendo de que las entidades
>   del dominio son objetos que tienen una identidad y son importantes
>   dentro de la lógica de negocio de nuestra aplicación, pero que no
>   tienen porque ser conocidos directamente por otras capas de la
>   aplicación.

Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto.

[image: Estructura N-Capas]

Estoy utilizando **DTOs** o ***Data Transfer Objects*** son clases cuyo principal objetivo es simplificar los objetos que se van a intercambiar entre procesos.

En la ***Capa de Aplicación***, en la cual tengo dos proyectos: *Servicos de Aplicación* y *Adaptadores*.

- **Adaptadores:** Es aquí donde tengo implementado mis DTOs.
- **Servicios de Aplicación:** Es en esta capa donde implemento los métodos de la aplicación, ya que mi Capa de presentación es ignorante de la Capa de Dominio y viseversa. Regresando al tema es en esta capa donde hago la magia de que las Entidades del Dominio se convierten en DTOs por medio de AutoMapper.

Entidades de Dominio.

```
public class Proveedor
{
    public int ProveedorId { get; set; }
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
}
```

DTOs

```
public class ProveedorDto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProveedorId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Razón Social")]
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Dirección")]
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
}
```

Aplicando AutoMapper en Servicios de Aplicación.

```
public IEnumerable<ProveedorDto> GetAll()
    {
        IEnumerable<Proveedor> _proveedor = _sdProveedor.GetAll();
        config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Proveedor, ProveedorDto>());
        IEnumerable<ProveedorDto> listDto = config.CreateMapper().Map<IEnumerable<ProveedorDto>>(_proveedor);
        return listDto;
    }
```

De esta manera es que mis Entidades del Dominio no llegan a la Capa de Presentación y los DTOs que estan en la Capa de Adaptadores son usados como los Models del patrón de diseño MVC.

- ***¿Debo crear los Models en la Capa de Presentación, tengo que pegarme a la letra de que los Models vayan implementados en esa capa, tal cual lo dice MVC?***
- ***¿Como debo implementar esa parte que he explicado, usando buenas prácticas para que quede prolija mi arquitectura?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo

De hecho es lo contrario toda la aplicación debe conocer al dominio. La idea detrás de DDD es crear un modelo del negocio o sea un caja negra que trabaja y resuelve problemas propias del negocio.

Entonces el enfoque va dirigido en crear un ecosistema donde las entidades interactúen y colaboren.

El concepto para que quede mas claro seria algo como: el sol con su propia existencia tiene un efecto, su luz su gravedad afecta a los planetas el clima, asi debe ser cada evento que se presente en el dominio.

En tu modelo eso debe suceder si tengo un sistema contable y una factura debe ingresar al enviar el mensaje al modelo este debe validar, afectar otras entidades y registrar si es necesario o tal vez modificar algo.

Toda esa lógica se encapsula en el dominio de tal manera que las operaciones no son las típicas:

_repisitorio.facturas.add(factura)

si no

model.Facturas.RegistrarFactura(factura)

En genera toda las lógica la encapsulas en un dominio capaz de procesar las operaciones propias del mismo lo que lo hace muy valioso.

También es importante mencionar que un dominio no tiene que ver con la persistencia por que debería poder funcionar sin la misma aun que un dominio sin persistencia es casi inútil.

Ahora la razón de usar transformaciones de objetos del dominio al usuario es por que en mvc los resultados se hacen a través de un viewmodel y en un dominio un concepto puede puede involucrar un tipo de colaboración entre las entidades de negocio lo que no lo hace candidato para representar de cara al usuario.

por ejemplo puedes tener una orden de compra y sus items y el usuario desde la ui se visualiza la orden de compra y la cantidad de items, obviamente esto se tiene que procesar y resultado llenara un viewmodel listo para visualizar

Otro concepto importante es que al estar enfocado a un Dominio ya no se habla de concepto aislados por ejemplo ante era típico algo tener entidades como

Emp ahora es Empleado. Sencillo, no?

Las entidades deben ser comunes entre todas las personas del equipo es lo que se llama lenguaje Ubiquitous, se puede decir que el lenguaje coloquial no debe haber abstraciones como antes sucedia si no que deberias poder platicar con el experto del negocio de los mismos conceptos.

También es importante que para modelar el dominio este no nace en tu cabeza, el dominio de un negocio ya existe siempre, lo que se hace es hablar con lo que conocen el negocio y luego esto lo se pasa al código, por eso es importante entender bien como funciona si no es posible que dejes vacíos y por lo tanto no pueda resolver todos los problemas.

Revisa el libro de Eric Evans, Domain Drive Design

> Vamos directo al problema que tengo. Partiendo de que las entidades
>   del dominio son objetos que tienen una identidad y son importantes
>   dentro de la lógica de negocio de nuestra aplicación, pero que no
>   tienen porque ser conocidos directamente por otras capas de la
>   aplicación.

Falso, se ven a todos los niveles pero no necesariamente los tiene que conocer el usuario.

- ¿Debo crear los Models en la Capa de Presentación, tengo que pegarme
  a la letra de que los Models vayan implementados en esa capa, tal
  cual lo dice MVC?

  Como se implementa en mvc no tiene que ver con ddd pero un punto importante, las acciones están muy relacionadas a un view model que como su nombre lo dice es un modelo de la vista o sea de la pagina el cual no tiene nada que ver con tu dominio por que su razón de ser es la vista o la pagina y esto es un concepto manejando en mvc.
- ¿Como debo implementar esa parte que he explicado, usando buenas
  prácticas para que quede prolija mi arquitectura?

  No hay una receta tu tienes que documentarte.

Comment: Hola, Carlos entonces creando un ViewModel tendría que aplicar automapper en la capa de presentación para convertir las entidades de negocio en ViewModel y viceversa. Me podrías compartir algún link para documentarme de como debo afrontar los ViewModel.

Answer (score 4):

Creo que es importante tener clara la diferencia entre teoría y práctica. A lo largo de la aplicación te vas a encontrar en muchas situaciones que te pueden obligar a romper ese teoría en pos de la productividad y la eficiencia. Ya queda en ti, como arquitecto de la aplicación, tomar esa decisión.

Desde mi experiencia personal, los modelos no pintan nada en la capa de presentación. Yo empecé teniéndolos en la capa de persistencia, que es su sitio ideal, para acabar en una capa  trasversal a todas llamada "Infraestructura", ya que de una forma u otra, era fácil acabar necesitando su referencia en otras capas.
En teoría, todo lo relacionado con persistencia, modelos incluidos, deben ubicarse en dicha capa. El dominio no debería tener ninguna relación con modelos ni saber de su existencia.

Si eres un purista de las arquitecturas y eres capaz de reducir el acoplamiento entre capas a cero, habrás llegado a la arquitectura ideal, pero insisto en que muchas veces es necesario romper esas reglas y hacer las cosas con cabeza. Cuando pase el tiempo y lleves mucho tiempo trabajando con la aplicación, te irás dando cuenta de las cosas que has hecho bien y de las que has hecho mal.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, buena respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

Para las páginas mvc se utilizan custom view models, que es un modelo diseñado para esa pagina web y  se rellena con los datos de las entidades del dominio que son DTO. Haces un peticion a la capa de negocio, que te devuelve un objeto del dominio (dto) y lo mapeas a tu custom view model. De esta forma te creas modelos locales a tus paginas web a tu gusto que se pueden nutrir de uno o varios objetos del dominio.