# ASP.NET MVC - Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy trabajando con el patrón de diseño MVC, tengo una arquitectura tres capas, ¿es necesario poner los modelos en la carpeta Models?, ¿los modelos pueden ir en otro proyecto?

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta te fue de utilidad para marcarla como aceptada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un sistema de más capas, pero para trabajar los modelos tengo los mismos elementos tanto en la carpeta de Models del proyecto web como en el proyecto de modelos. Te pondré un ejemplo.

```
namespace ProyModelo
public class ProyModPersona {
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Nombre { get; set;}
    public bool Activo { get; set;}
}

namespace ProyWeb.Models
public class PersonaModel {
    public int Id;
    public string Nombre;
    public bool Activo;
}
```

En esencia son iguales, inclusive si necesitas utilizar tags que solo funcionan en tu frontend los puedes aplicar sin problema ya que la única condición que se necesita es que las propiedades tengan el mismo nombre y tipo de dato.

Ahora, hay algo importante que debes de utilizar para que funcione correctamente al momento de manejar el flujon de datos. Hay una herramienta que puedes utilizar que se llama AutoMapper, la cual te sirve para igualar tus modelos de datos; en este caso tus modelos de ProyModelo con los de ProyWeb.Models. Suelo hacer este procedimiento en el controlador cs.

AutoMapper lo puedes instalar desde el mismo Nuget Package de visual.

Por ejemplo, sí quisiera psara un objeto desde el frontend al backend haría una conversión como:

```
PersonaModel objPersonaModel  = ObjectMapper.Instance.Convert<ProyModPersona , PersonaModel >(objModPersona);
```

Y también funciona se debe hacer de backend a frontend.
Lo bueno de todo esto es que funciona con todo tipo de estructura de dato, llamese listas, ViewModels, etc.

Espero que esto resuelva tu problemática.

Answer (score 1):

Puede utilizar un modelo desde cualquier lugar.

Asegúrese de que su MVC proyecto tiene una referencia al otro proyecto que contiene los modelos.

También asegúrese de que el controlador y la vista han importado el espacio de nombres de los modelos del otro proyecto.

Con proyecto nuevo en visual studio - Aspx MvC 2 (Debería funcionar para cualquier versión, la misma idea)

**La solución**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**el controlador**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Test()
        {

            TestModel model = new TestModel();

            model.Name = "This is Testing!";

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

**El modelo del otro proyecto ClassLibrary1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**La vista**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="ClassLibrary1" %>
<asp:Content ID="aboutTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    <%= (((TestModel)Model).Name) %>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="aboutContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%= (((TestModel)Model).Name) %></h2>
    <p>
        Put content here.
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Yo lo he hecho de una forma similar y funciona aunque a veces es necesario estar actualizando los name spaces. La inquietud es si se considera una buena práctica,  si aporta valor o por el contrario afecta cosas como el rendimiento.

Comment: @Fpme tengo un proyecto en n-capas igual tengo los models en otra capa http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41889/asp-net-mvc-arquitectura-ddddomain-driven-design estoy a la espera que contesten los expertos en ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Un beneficio de esto es para compartir una biblioteca de modelos comunes. Un inconveniente es que ahora eres responsable de mantener esta biblioteca sincronizada con otros sistemas.

Comment: yo manejo los modelos como un proyecto de biblioteca de clases, en una carpeta independiente y mi proyecto MVC hace referencia a la DLL